# How to manage different Apps that Call same Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, azure-active-directory

I've a web api (.net core 3.1) and for authentication i'm using the Active Directory Authentication (B2C).

I've 3 different apps that call the Api :

- Ios App
- Android App
- Web App

My Question is : 
How can i know which app was the caller and after do the specific redirect for each app ?

In AD i've to set a redirect url after authentication so i think that in the method called in redirect i've to redirect to the right frontend url.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question `string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();`?

Comment: `UserAgent` can also be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can get caller's information and based on that you can write your logic.

```
string caller = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

**Note:** Be aware, it can be spoofed.

I am not sure that the caller always provide this information.

Comment: the flow is :
1. login page (all clients app call same login page url)
2. authentication succed
3. AD redirect to web api url


at this point i still have have the referer ?